# log4j property error

Tags: java, log4j

I have an application which uses `log4j` to send its log via `syslog` to a central logging application. Although the log4j is successful in sending the app messages, the messages themselves do not have the syslog header (containing the time stamp, host name, etc.).

I am trying to figure out how can I append the syslog header to each log line from the application.

Below is my configuration

```
log4j.logger.com.axeda.esrs=INFO, SYSLOG log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}: %m%n log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=syslog_destination
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=LOCAL0
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.FacilityPrinting=false
```

I added the following property to the conf.:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
```

But after restarting the process, I get the following error in the log file:

```
log4j:WARN No such property [header] in org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
```

Can you please tell me how I can add the syslog header into each log event.

```
log sample currently in use without the syslog header: <134>2012-11-02 16:22:30,451: EMC Policy Manager Audit: Fri Nov 02 16:22:30 CEST 2012, CK0000000, System, Remote Session 5171112upPI4v4Hp3FrHJbSOxiHZ7aEp3crZNwngP8ZrLw625 started on device CK292603612 with model Symmetrix-GW by remote user 00000 from enterprise servicelinkcluster at Fri Nov 02 16:19:52 CEST 2012
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try setting it in code? Using [`.setHeader`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html#setHeader%28boolean%29)

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: No, because I've never done it before. If I could I would have done it as an answer. Notice my previous comment was a link to the javadoc

Answer (score 0):

I think header's H must be small... So property name must be log4j.appender.SYSLOG.header=true.

By Looking at the class file, it looks header is a property of the class http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html. So while defining properties we start them with LOWER_CHAR... You can give it a try...

Comment: Vishal, I already tried that. But it didnt work. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an old log4j version? The header property on SyslogAppender was added in 1.2.15. I saw the same warning you're getting while I was configuring an existing system to log to Papertrail, and I found that something in my build process was pulling in an older log4j version.